# Bug in Suggesting Edits

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I've suggested an edit using the desktop web version of Stack Overflow on a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075365/how-to-get-my-php-form-to-work.

However, there's no confirmation after suggesting the edit is suggested, usually, there will be a notification:

> You do not have edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

(No confirmation message is shown)

[image: Screenshot 1]

And I can continue to edit it again:

[image: Screenshot 2]

But, in the iOS App, the edit can be seen:

[image: Screenshot 3]

After clicking on `Edit (1)`:

[image: Screenshot 4]

I've repeatedly tried this thrice. Is the suggested edit successfully saved or is this a bug?

Also, if it's not successful saved, why does the iOS App shows it?

**Update:**

The suggested edit is now accepted:

[image: Screenshot 5]

Comment: Can't see it anywhere in your profile, and there's no pending/accepted edits visible on that question

Comment: @Rob Not sure why, but it was just accepted, updated post to reflect that